# Using a escape function in Swift to allow the use of parameters

Tags: swift, xcode

I am new to this escape function in Swift, but I follow a tutorial and I use the following function below: (the function is working for me)

```
static func showThreeOptions(messageText: String, titleOne:String, titleTwo: String, actionOne: @escaping () -> (Void), actionTwo: @escaping () -> (), currentView: UIViewController  ) {
    
    // create the alert
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alerta", message: messageText, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    // add the actions (buttons)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: titleOne, style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { (alert) in
        actionOne()
    } ))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: titleTwo, style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { (alert) in
        actionTwo()
    } ))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancelar", style: UIAlertAction.Style.destructive, handler: nil))
    // show the alert
    currentView.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now, I want to change the *actionTwo()* to *actionTwo(number:Int)*,

but I don't know how to change the signature *actionTwo: @escaping () -> ()*

How can I change the signature
*actionTwo: @escaping () -> ()* to allow to be able to call *actionTwo(number:Int)* ?

-----UPDATE-----

I create the function
actionTwo(2) and it works. Thank you @RobNapier

But there is another problem now.

I call the function

```
AlertActions.showThreeOptions(
        messageText: "Resenha Finalizada.",
        titleOne: "Marcas/Fotos",
        titleTwo: "Editar",
        actionOne: self.someHandlerOne,
        actionTwo: self.someHandlerTwo(2),
        currentView: self
    )
```

This is the functions

```
func someHandlerOne() {
    print("test")
}

func someHandlerTwo(_ id:Int) {
    print("test2")
}
```

Now I get the following error when I call *someHandlerTwo(_ id:Int)*

Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '(Int) -> ()'

How can I fix that error?

-----UPDATE 2-----

I find out how to use a escaping function now

```
func notImplemented(resDado_id: Int) -> () {
    print(resDado_id)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `@escaping () -> ()` to `@escaping (Int) -> ()`. Instead of something that takes no parameters, you want something that takes one.

It's a little nicer to use Void for return values that are (), like `(Int) -> Void`, but it means the same thing.

Comment: Just like you said I change escaping () -> () to escaping (Int) -> (). But when I try change actionTwo() to actionTwo(number:Int) the compiler complains and show the error Extraneous argument label 'number:' in call. I click on the error and click on fix, after that it shows another error Cannot convert value of type '(Int).Type' to expected argument type 'Int'

Comment: Your call to `action2` should be: `actionTwo(2)` (where 2 is whatever Int value you want to pass). There cannot be a label when calling a closure.

Comment: The error Cannot convert value of type '(Int).Type' to expected argument type 'Int' is showed when I try to use the following function actionThree(Int)

Comment: `Int` is not a value. It's the name of type. You need to pass the integer you want to pass.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is a different approach:

Write an extension of `UIViewController` and use the `UIAlertAction` handler signature for `actionOne` and `actionTwo`.

This is still more versatile and the `UIAlertAction` handler closures don't escape

```
extension UIViewController {
    func showThreeOptions(messageText: String, titleOne:String, titleTwo: String, actionOne: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)? = nil, actionTwo: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)? = nil) {
        
        // create the alert
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alerta", message: messageText, preferredStyle: .alert)
        // add the actions (buttons)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: titleOne, style: .default, handler: actionOne))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: titleTwo, style: .default, handler: actionTwo))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancelar", style: .destructive, handler: nil))
        // show the alert
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The closures can even be declared as functions for example

```
func actionOne(action : UIAlertAction) {
    //
}
```

**Edit:**

You don't need to pass a parameter, you can create the handler inline and capture the `id`

```
func deleteSomething(at id: Int) {
    let handler : (UIAlertAction) -> Void = { action in
        db.deletarResDados(id: id)
    }
    showThreeOptions(messageText: "Resenha Finalizada.",
                     titleOne: "Marcas/Fotos",
                     titleTwo: "Editar", 
                     actionOne: nil, 
                     actionTwo: handler)
}
```

Comment: I update the question now, this suggestion is very interesting, but now how can I pass an Int paramter inside the actionOne function?

Comment: How is this `Int` parameter supposed to be used?

Comment: I'll use the Int value with another function to delete a row in a database. This is the function *func excluirResenha(idForDelete id:Int){
        db.deletarResDados(id: id)
    }*